# named import throws errors whereas import * from doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, jestjs

Consider the following folder structure for features in my react app:

```
feature1
    actions
        actionTypes.js
        crud.js
    component.js
    container.js
    reducer.js
    sagas.js
    sagas.test.js
    services.js
    index.js


feature2
    actions
        actionTypes.js
        crud.js
    component.js
    container.js
    reducer.js
    sagas.js
    sagas.test.js
    services.js
    index.js
```

In the `index.js` files, I'm importing the component, container, reducer etc. of each respective feature and have exported the same from the index file.

ex: `feature1/index.js`

```
import myReducer from './reducer';
import * as mySagas from './sagas';
import * as myServices from './services';
import * as myCRUD from './actions/crud';
import Component from './component';
import Container from './container';
import * as actionTypes from './actions/actionTypes';

export {
  myReducer,
  actionTypes,
  myCRUD,
  mySagas,
  myServices,
  Component,
  Container,
};
```

Now in the `sagas.test.js` file of `feature2`, I can import services of feature1 as follows:

`import { myServices } from '../feature1';`

The above line causes a failure: `TypeError: window.locale_name is not a function` when I run my Jest tests. `window.locale_name` is a function defined in a third-party library that's imported in `feature1`. But on the other hand, if I import the same in the following way, no error is thrown.

`import * as myServices from '../feature1/services';`

Comment: Does `feature1` have a named export? or a default export?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the imported `myServices` depends on `window.locale_name` being set. Could the reason importing `*` works is because among the exported values of `feature1/index.js`, one of them that is exported before `myServices` sets the `window.locale_name` that your `myServices` would be using?

I believe with ES6 modules, only the export code you import is run to be able to have tree shaking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that was not it. I tried exporting `myServices` as the last item in the index.js file, but to no avail.

Comment: @cbalawat it doesn't matter where you put myServices in the export; if you import with destructuring, its dependency will not be loaded, and your script will fail. Try exporting myServices as the first item in the file, and import with '* as', and you should see it fail for the same reason that its dependency was not loaded.